# Analysis of Likert scale

Tags: multivariate-analysis, likert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Analysis of part of Likert scale](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27786/analysis-of-part-of-likert-scale)

My survey consist of 6 airlines (non metric) and 10 attributes for rating these airlines. The questionnaire uses 5 point likert scale. Only one airline can be rated using one questionnaire. The questionnaire has 10 questions, each one regarding one attributes.

My concerns are:

- What are the dependent and independent variable?
- Whether the attributes rating using Likert scale are metric values or non metric values.
- My final objective is to sort out the best airline based on the ratings obtained from the passengers.

Based on the dependent and independent variables which analytical tool have to be used so that i can compare the airlines based on each attributes.
For example: if one attribute is "safety", i have end up in a result that "airline B is more safer comapred to other airlines (A,C,D,E,F)

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts for yourself & re-asked your question. This seems to differ very little from your [previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27786/analysis-of-part-of-likert-scale). If answers provided do not give you what you need, you should edit the existing question &/or comment on existing answers, not ask again. You may want to read our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: I've merged your two accounts, jijo. Please [register it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login) (e.g., with your OpenID). Also, I'm closing this question as it is a duplicate of your previous one.