# Data normalization in SPSS statistics

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, spss, data-transformation, normalization

I am analyzing the responses of a survey using spss statistics.
I understand that I will need to do a Cronbach alpha first.
But here is my problem:

The first part of my survey is "Awareness" and second part is "Attitudes".
Under "Attitudes",there are 6 likert scale questions and 4 yes/no questions. So i was told to do data normalization before calculating Cronbach alpha for "Attitudes".

How should I do data normalization in spss?

Is data normalization same as transforming data in SPSS (arithmetric eg. Log10 or square root)? If so, how should I transform the yes/no questions? (my understanding is we can only transform likert-scale question)

I found very limited information in data normalization using spss.

Your answer is deeply appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Comment: "[I] was told to do data normalization": what did your boss say exactly. It's hard to see how Likert-scale questions can be "normalized".

Answer (score 1):

To normalize means to rescale so that the range becomes [0,1].  See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/whats-the-difference-between-normalization-and-standardization).  Normalizing to bring your [1,5] responses into a [0,1] range will not help you assess reliability.  (They're not Likert responses--they're ordinal ratings.  See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/general-advice-on-forming-an-index-of-attitude-to-the-environment-from-a-set-of).)

If you are willing to run the Cronbach's alpha procedure on the 1-5 ratings, you arguably can also do so on the larger group of items that includes the binary items.  It may not have been Cronbach's original intent to use non-continuous data, but think of it like computing a correlation using two binary variables.  Instead of calling it *r* you would call it *phi*; it serves the same purpose and in many situations is an adequate indicator.