# Which type of data are answers to this question, and which test should I use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, scales, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Which type of data are answers to this scale?

How is your sleep quality?

Very bad     -    Very good

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Would answers to this question be ordinal / nominal / interval / or ratio data?

If I want to test the statistical difference in the means for paired samples before and after taking a medicine that is supposed to improve sleep quality, should I use paired samples t-test or Wilcoxon Signed-Ranks Test?

Thanks!

Comment: Ordinal and Wilcoxon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good basic statistics to use for ordinal data?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97/what-are-good-basic-statistics-to-use-for-ordinal-data), http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203/group-differences-on-a-five-point-likert-item, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10382/general-advice-on-forming-an-index-of-attitude-to-the-environment-from-a-set-of/10522#10522​